# What constitutes a unique research paper?

Tags: publications, publishability

I have been working on a particular algorithm. It has many applications and I have found one for which a dataset is available as well as other algorithms used to parse that dataset. But the algorithm I am studying hasn’t been applied to that dataset as far as I know. If I implement that algorithm on the dataset, I don’t think I will be making significant changes to it. Will it still be considered as enough of a result to publish a paper?

I am an undergrad; if that is relevant.

Comment: Do you have a supervisor who you can ask about such things? They would probably have the best idea.

Comment: How about a conference? Many new researchers start with a conference paper because in most cases the bar for novelty and depth is quite low, but it gives you experience writing up a proceedings paper. The work can later be expanded to a journal paper. The main disadvantage to a conference is cost of travel and registration.

Comment: In computer science, conference papers are generally considered to be at the same level of accomplishment as journal papers.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I understand that in CS the highest impact conferences are equivalent or better than the best journals (e.g. SIGGRAPH) but I find it hard to believe that _all_ conferences are of the same level as reasonable journals. For example, this group has listed a number of tier 3 and tier 4 conferences in distributed computing: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/group/pmrs/conference-journal-tiers/

Comment: @user71659 You misunderstand what I said. It's certainly not the case that all conferences are as good as all respected journals, but I am reasonably confident when I say that all conferences are as reputable as some journal. Unlike in other fields, conference vs journal is not a good predictor of impact factor or how well regarded the result is.

Comment: @user71659 In addition to what Stella said, keep in mind that there's also mid- and low-tier journals, rather than only top journals - a publication in a poor journal has very little value. However, actually, there's a main advantage of conferences that you didn't mention: the feedback cycle of conferences is usually faster than that of journals, which makes them particularly attractive to get feedback when starting a new research direction.

Comment: @StellaBiderman You're also making the assumption that because the question used the word "algorithm" that the field of CS is the only applicable field. For example, a denoising or foreground separation algorithm in astrophysics, or a computational imaging algorithm. Those would not necessarily be published in a CS journal.

Comment: @user71659 That is true, I read this question and assumed it was about CS

Comment: @user71659 how low is the bar for novelty in conferences ? how much can we get away with ? would appreciate some elaboration !

Answer (score 3):

The following is general guidelines under the assumption that you're looking at this as a computer science project. If you specify the field, I can modify this advice accordingly. For advice about a particular project, you'll have to share the details of your project with someone with experience publishing in CS or whatever field you're working in.

The bar is, roughly, "is this something people would want to read." When you try to present new work to an audience, your job is pretty much to sell the arbiter (be it dissertation adviser, journal referee, or conference organizer) that the work that you did is something people would be interested in reading and using.

The most important question is: have other people used this algorithm, on any data set, before? If the answer is "no" than your work is almost certainly publishable, especially as it sounds like your algorithm preforms comparably well to other algorithms that preform the same or similar task. Your paper should explicitly analyze this and seek to give examples of data sets or contexts in which your algorithm out-preforms known algorithms.

If the answer is "yes," then your work may or may not be publishable. Applying a well-known algorithm like the [Gale-Shipley Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) or [Diijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to some random data set isn't generally going to be considered interesting because any researcher who is interested in this data set could do that, and the fact that no one has indicates that people don't currently care to. However, if you use a known algorithm to find an unexpected or surprising result then your project might still be publishable, and the more surprising or interesting the conclusions you can draw are, the more publishable the algorithm is. Here the strength of your paper is going to be determined by the data analysis you do, and how you show that your work is connected to work people are already interested in.

For example, I do a lot of research on social networks, and one hot topic in social network analysis is the detecting of communities inside of a broader social network. For the second approach, if you create a new algorithm for community detection, you can write a paper about your new algorithm comparing it to old algorithms and pointing out data sets where your algorithm is preferred. If you take a known community detection algorithm and use it to show that communities in certain types of graphs have an interesting property, that would be publishable. Additionally, you can somewhat blend these two cases if you were to take a known algorithm and show how it can be used for community detection, while everyone else is using it for some other purpose.

Comment: I disagree that the bar is "something people want to read" in many fields. The bar is often "is it something that should be reported because somebody may find it useful". For example, in astrophysics, the highest cited papers are often reports of observations, because people later use the data. (Leading to the phenomena that Astrophysical Journal Supplement has a higher impact factor than ApJ, but with a much lower bar). Likewise, a negative result is still useful in the record so that nobody wastes time trying it again.

Comment: @user71659 My answer explicit states that it's about computer science. Also, observations and negative results are both things that people would want to read, or read summaries of. I really don't see what the meaning of your objection is, or what it would even mean to have a publishable article that no one is interested in reading.

Comment: "Read" is too strong. Nobody wants to read a paper that shows the spectrum to a star. It means nothing in itself. I want to _use_ the data to support my model. So quite literally, you skim the methodology to see if it sounds valid, and copy the data points.

Comment: @user71659 In the strongest sense of the term, I "read" 10 or even 20 papers for every one that I read. If it makes you happy you can think "skim" or "read a summary of" where I say read, but in my experience no one uses language the way you're implying. Can you explain what the purpose this objection has besides nitpicking that I'm using terminology as is widely used as opposed to how the dictionary says it should be?

Comment: I think I'm very clear. The criteria for mid and low-tier journals is best stated as "is this paper **useful** to a researcher in the field?". Certainly _Science_, _Nature_ and _Communications of the ACM_ heavily apply an "interesting" factor. But as I said, there's lots of uninteresting or even repetitive, but useful observations you can publish, like plain data and negative observations.